# Excel VBA Coding Issues

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help on how to solve the below problem using Excel VBA Code. I have 2 tables. Table 1 content rows of data and Table 2 contents row of variables. Basically I need to perform string comparison between these 2 tables and then once match, I need to take the match variable from Table 2 and write on the Table 1 under the same row number of match string. Sometimes there might be more matches available from Table 2. So I need to prompt a box to show the user the list of match variables and ask them to choose which one to use as replacement. If it is contain 1 variable match, I can replace directly

I able to perform comparison between these 2 tables and extract the info
(row number, data from table 1 and variable from table 2) into 3 different arrays. Now the question is how do I use these 3 different arrays to do manipulations of writing the variables into excel data table.

Below shows there are 3 arrays which are match1 which store row number of data table 1. The matchstr1 shows the variable from table 2 and tmpstr is a data from Table 1.

match1[1] = 2

matchstr1[1] = modelSelectionmadeInAmerica

tmpstr1[1] = *ModelSelectionMadeInAmerica*

match1[2] = 3

matchstr1[2] = configurationType_A

tmpstr1[2] = *ConfigurationType*

match1[3] = 4

matchstr1[3] = ctrStationpowerSupply_A

tmpstr1[3] = *PowerSupply*

match1[4] = 4

matchstr1[4] = confPowerSupply_B

tmpstr1[4] = *PowerSupply*

match1[5] = 4

matchstr1[5] = KitPowerSupplyRequired_C

tmpstr1[5] = *PowerSupply*

match1[6] = 5

matchstr1[6] = CHSirenAndLightsKeypadPrinting_D

tmpstr1[6] = *CHSirenandLightsKeypadPrinting*

match1[7] = 6

matchstr1[7] = DREnableDR_E

tmpstr1[7] = *DREnableDR*

I have been struggling to find a solution for this problem for the past 3 days with loops but it is not working as expected or required.

Below is how the code look like

Option Compare Text

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim attr1 As Range, data1 As Range
Dim item1, item2, item3, lastRow, lastRow2
Dim UsrInput, UsrInput2 As Variant
Dim Cnt As Integer, LineCnt As Integer
Dim MatchData(1 To 9000) As String
Dim i As Integer, n As Integer, j As Integer
Dim counter1 As Integer, counter2 As Integer
Dim match1(1 To 500) As Integer
Dim matchstr1(1 To 500) As String
Dim tmpstr1(1 To 500) As String


counter1 = 1
counter2 = 0
j = 0

For i = 1 To 500
    tmpstr1(i) = ""
Next i

For i = 1 To 500
    matchstr1(i) = ""
Next i

For i = 1 To 500
    match1(i) = 0
Next i

For i = 1 To 9000
    MatchData(i) = ""
Next i

UsrInput = InputBox("Enter Atribute Column")
UsrInput2 = InputBox("Enter Column Alphabet to compare")

With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, UsrInput).End(xlUp).Row
    'MsgBox lastRow
End With

With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, UsrInput2).End(xlUp).Row
    'MsgBox lastRow
End With


Set attr1 = Range(UsrInput & "2:" & UsrInput & lastRow)
Set data1 = Range(UsrInput2 & "2:" & UsrInput2 & lastRow)


For Each item1 In attr1
    item1.Value = Replace(item1.Value, " ", "")
Next item1

For Each item1 In attr1
     If item1 = "" Then Exit For
     counter1 = counter1 + 1
     item1 = "*" & item1 & "*"

     For Each item2 In data1
           If item2 = "" Then Exit For
           If item2 Like item1 Then
                counter2 = counter2 + 1
                match1(counter2) = counter1
                matchstr1(counter2) = item2.Value
                tmpstr1(counter2) = item1
'                Debug.Print "match1[" & counter2; "] = " & match1(counter2)
'                Debug.Print "matchstr1[" & counter2; "] = " & matchstr1(counter2)
'                Debug.Print "tmpstr1[" & counter2; "] = " & tmpstr1(counter2)

            End If

    Next item2
 Next item1

 ' Need help here how to use the above array to replace the data in table 1 using the var from table 2.


End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: It might help if you supply the code that you have written, even if it is not working as expected. That would give people a better idea of what you are trying to accomplish. When you include the code describe *how* it is failing to meet expectations. If there are any run-time or syntax errors, say what they are and where they occur.

Comment: OK Let me put up the code. The above is Debug.Print statement that has been formatted like a C program array. It is it not a vba code. I will add the code now